# LinearPercentIndicator not displayed when defined in function Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm rather new to Flutter/Dart so I could have made a foolish mistake. I have defined a `LinearPercentIndicator` in what I believe is a function inside my class `_FourthRouteState`. I call this function inside `Widget build(BuildContext context)` with 3 parameters: context, var1, var2 where var1 is a `double` between 0.0 and 1.0 and var2 is a text object.

The default PercentIndicator should display 75% whereas if the user presses the **Confirm** button, the percentage should change to 100%. It would be ideal if the animation of the LinearPercentIndicator starts over, since the value changes from 75 to 100.

The problem is that the LinearPercentIndicator is not displayed on my page and I don't receive any errors so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. If you could both help me with my code (I only included the relevant parts) and provide me with some relevant/useful documentation, that would be great!

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:percent_indicator/percent_indicator.dart';
import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    theme:
    ThemeData(accentColor: Colors.black87),
    home: FourthRoute(),
  ));
}

class FourthRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  final value;

  FourthRoute({Key key, this.value}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FourthRouteState createState() => new _FourthRouteState();
}

class _FourthRouteState extends State<FourthRoute> {

  var _textController = new TextEditingController();

  var _formKey = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();

  getPercentageIndicator(context, var1,var2) {
    setState(() {
      LinearPercentIndicator(
        width: MediaQuery
            .of(context)
            .size
            .width - 50,
        animation: true,
        lineHeight: 20.0,
        animationDuration: 2000,
        percent: var1,
        center: Text(var2),
        linearStrokeCap: LinearStrokeCap.roundAll,
        progressColor: Colors.green,
        backgroundColor: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.2),
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Color foreground = Colors.green;
    Color background = foreground.withOpacity(0.2);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(53, 73, 94, 0.9)),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 0.0,
            left: 0.0,
            right: 0.0,
            child: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              elevation: 0.0,
            ),
          ),

          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50.0),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0,16.0,0.0,0.0), // left, top, right, bottom
                child: getPercentageIndicator(context,0.75,"75%"),
              ),
            ],
          ),

          Positioned(
            bottom: 150.0,
            right: 20.0,
            child: ButtonTheme(
              minWidth: 150.0,
              child: RaisedButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text('Confirm',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 24,
                        color: Colors.black87,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    ),
                  ),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0)
                  ),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                      getPercentageIndicator(context,1.0,"100%");
//                      Navigator.push(
//                        context,
//                        PageTransition(
//                          type: PageTransitionType.fade,
//                          child:HomePage(),
//                          duration: Duration(
//                              seconds: 1
//                          ),
//                        ),
//                      );
                    }
                  }
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you make instance of *LinearPercentIndicator* widget inside of *setState* in *getPercentageIndicator*? It makes no sense. You probably wanted just to return it:

```dart
  getPercentageIndicator(context, var1,var2) {
    return LinearPercentIndicator(
      width: MediaQuery
          .of(context)
          .size
          .width - 50,
      animation: true,
      lineHeight: 20.0,
      animationDuration: 2000,
      percent: var1,
      center: Text(var2),
      linearStrokeCap: LinearStrokeCap.roundAll,
      progressColor: Colors.green,
      backgroundColor: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.2),
    );
  }
```

By the way, you shouldn't use mediaquery size here. Use *LayoutBuilder* to change width depending on how much space your widget has:

```dart
  getPercentageIndicator(context, var1,var2) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        return LinearPercentIndicator(
          width: constraints.maxWidth - 50,
          animation: true,
          lineHeight: 20.0,
          animationDuration: 2000,
          percent: var1,
          center: Text(var2),
          linearStrokeCap: LinearStrokeCap.roundAll,
          progressColor: Colors.green,
          backgroundColor: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.2),
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: The initial instance works. If I would like to change the values in the PercentIndicator, so var1 and var2, when I click the **Confirm** button, would I need setState in `getPercentageIndicator`? Look at my post above for more detail as I've stated my question there too.

Comment: @Jack No, you can call *setState* straight from *onPressed* callback. Just add variable in your state that will store your current progress and change its value in *onPressed* callback with *setState* ;

Comment: Thank you @Igor Kharakhordin!